# what is the correct way to find address of file to use in a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I install a WordPress plugin that use a javascript file and it has custom filter. here is the code it use:

```
wp_register_script( 'pw-cities', apply_filters( 'woo_my_cities', PW()->plugin_url( 'assets/js/my_cities.min.js' ) ), false, PW_VERSION, true );
```

i want to create a plugin that use this custom hook and give address of another javascript file to it. I use this code in my plugin main php file

```
    function myCityFilter($path){
        $path= dirname(__FILE__) . "/assets/js/myCityList.js";
        return $path;
    }
    add_filter('woo_my_cities', 'myCityFilter');
```

It seems like it won't work correctly because the main plugin alert about missing javascript file. but when i change the path `https://localhost/wp-content/plugins/myCityFilter/assets/js/myCityLits.js` it works.
i assume if it was on a host server the addres have to start with https://example.com. how can I use php to produce something like that automatically? 
address started with `/var/www/html` produce the error,too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `dirname(__FILE__)` is returning the full filesystem path to your JavaScript file. What you want instead is the path to the JavaScript file relative to the document root of your application.

WordPress has a built-in [`plugins_url()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugins_url) method that you can use to get the path that you need. It should be something like:

```
$path = plugins_url('/assets/js/myCityList.js', __FILE__);
```

Comment: i check it. this code produce the error, too. why??

Comment: update: i made a mistake. the code works well. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `plugin_dir_url()` function as below in respect of your code

```
function myCityFilter($path){
        $path= plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . "assets/js/myCityList.js";
        return $path;
    }
    add_filter('woo_my_cities', 'myCityFilter');
```